# Translation for my database driven application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, localization, translation, language-translation

my application is a .NET Web based app that has a bunch of tables which contain strings that gets displayed in the UI.

I was going through some ways to get them translated and I found this- 'Translution'- http://www.translution.com/public/translution_database_translator.asp

Using this we can configure tables and columns for storing translated content and they translate them for us.

Has anybody here have used Translution before, if so, your feedback?

Could you guys also suggest me some other alternatives to my requirement?